# Why does my GMP installation not progress?

Tags: installation, makefile, mingw, freeze, gmp

I want to install the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) on my Windows environment. Hence I followed [the documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP.html#Installing-GMP) by starting a Git bash (in Adminstrator mode) which uses MinGW and typing from within the decompressed gmp archive:

1. `./configure` => works fine, no error messages were generated
2. `make` => does not proceed (as if it hangs) after the following command was issued:

[image: a git bash window with the frozen state of a gmp make call]

As nothing has changed for hours I guess there is no progress happening in the background. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What does the process manager say that process is doing? Using any cpu or memory? That's a large list of things to link together and mingw isn't exactly speedy. I wouldn't have expected it to take hours but I would have expected a fairly long time.

Comment: It uses 0 % of the CPU and 0,1 MB of the memory. This is why I am so confused.

Comment: You could try something like Process Monitor (or even Process Explorer) from SysInternals to see more of what it is doing (the way you would use strace/etc. on linux) and see if that gives you an indication of what might be going on.

Comment: Looks like you did ok. Maybe try again, in case you were just unlucky the first time? If it hangs again, maybe report it to mingw.

Comment: @EtanReisner I could not find any valuable information inside Process Monitor

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yeah, it seems to be quite random. I found out that sometimes it works for the mpn folder and then it proceeds with the mpz folder which hangs, once again.

Comment: I do not want to waste more time. Therefore I just installed LinuxMint as a virtual machine where gmp is conveniently provided via a package.

Comment: Why do you want to mess with GMP on Windows? MPIR is an API-compatible replacement, which is also windows-friendly.

Comment: Even better: since my code is compiled with cygwin's gcc I was just able to use cygwin's GMP as well!